# What determine the order of the runs in TensorBoard's embeddings tab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, embedding, tensorboard

What determine the order of the runs in TensorBoard's embeddings tab?

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are those values timestamps of when the runs were started?

Comment: @danielunderwood yes. ISO format. The other tabs follow the  lexicographical order, but not the embedding tab.

Comment: Oops. I misread your question and thought it was about determining order rather than the runs being displayed in a weird order. It may be worth opening up an issue on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) since I'd imagine that this isn't the intended ordering and there aren't any existing issues like that.

Comment: @danielunderwood Sounds good I'll do it tomorrow if I don't get any satisfactory answer by then.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt  I opened a GitHub issue: [Ordering the runs in TensorBoard's embeddings tab #8255](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TensorBoard embedding project backend [serves the runs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/100552f943c78cbf90aad521f9981df9b5e3c738/tensorflow/tensorboard/plugins/projector/projector_plugin.py#L277) as a list of keys in a Python `dict` object:

```
@wrappers.Request.application
def _serve_runs(self, request):
  """Returns a list of runs that have embeddings."""
  return Respond(request, list(self.configs.keys()), 'application/json')
```

Quoting the Python [documentation for Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> Performing list(d.keys()) on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just use sorted(d.keys()) instead).

Comment: Thanks, I opened a GitHub issue: [Ordering the runs in TensorBoard's embeddings tab #8255](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8255)

Answer (score 2):

**Update Oct 2020:**

It's now sorted by run-time for the experiment:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/538eaeb53076943408d8026a7194ddb50168a77d/tensorboard/plugins/core/core_plugin.py#L171

I wish there was an option to sort it alphabetically/run-time, etc, as per one's choice...